# Reemplazo de valores duplicados en columnas distintas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Cuento con el siguiente dataframe:

```
Year-Week    Case    Team     Case Info
2022-42      540    Finance    OTHER
2022-42      540    IT         ACCEPTED
2022-42      480    Sales      OTHER
2022-42      480    Finance    CHECK CASE
2022-42      480    IT         OTHER
2022-42      465    IT         OTHER
2022-42      465    Sales      OTHER
2022-42      310    Legal      VALIDATED
2022-42      310    Marketing  OTHER
```

Como se puede ver, existen valores duplicados en el apartado de "Case", esto es porque cada caso puede pertenecer a un equipo distinto y cada equipo puede categorizar al caso de manera distinta en el apartado de "Case Info".

Mi problema radica en que quisiera que mi código de python tomase los casos duplicados "Case" y cuando cuentan con valor distinto en "Case Info", predomine cualquier otro valor que no sea el de "OTHER", adjunto un ejemplo:

```
Year-Week    Case    Team     Case Info
2022-42      540    Finance    ACCEPTED
2022-42      540    IT         ACCEPTED
2022-42      480    Sales      CHECK CASE
2022-42      480    Finance    CHECK CASE
2022-42      480    IT         CHECK CASE
2022-42      465    IT         OTHER
2022-42      465    Sales      OTHER
2022-42      310    Legal      VALIDATED
2022-42      310    Marketing  VALIDATED
```

He estado tratando de usar comandos como:

```
df['Case Info'] = df.groupby('Case')['Case Info'].transform('max')
```

Pero eso solo me lleva a reemplazar un solo valor por otro, por el orden de las letras iniciales de la tabla ASCII. Habiendo dicho eso, lo anterior solo hace la mitad del trabajo, ya que solo lo está haciendo para un solo valor de la columna 'OTHER'.

De la misma forma, intenté de la siguiente manera, pero en lugar de reemplazar los valores de 'OTHER' como en el output deseado, me arroja todos los valores de Case Info igual a 'OTHER'

```
df.groupby('Case')['Case Info'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('OTHER',np.nan).bfill().ffill()) # This should return your wanted series
```

El output que estoy obteniendo es el siguiente, lo cual está mal:

```
Year-Week    Case    Team     Case Info
2022-42      540    Finance    OTHER
2022-42      540    IT         OTHER
2022-42      480    Sales      OTHER
2022-42      480    Finance    OTHER
2022-42      480    IT         OTHER
2022-42      465    IT         OTHER
2022-42      465    Sales      OTHER
2022-42      310    Legal      OTHER
2022-42      310    Marketing  OTHER
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Yo creo que algo estás haciendo de más antes de la última línea de tu código que dices devuelve el `dataframe` incorrecto

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  Year-Week  Case       Team   Case Info
0   2022-42   540    Finance       OTHER
1   2022-42   540         IT    ACCEPTED
2   2022-42   480      Sales       OTHER
3   2022-42   480    Finance  CHECK CASE
4   2022-42   480         IT       OTHER
5   2022-42   465         IT       OTHER
6   2022-42   465      Sales       OTHER
7   2022-42   310      Legal   VALIDATED
8   2022-42   310  Marketing       OTHER
```

Con el siguiente código obtenemos el resultado deseado:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year-Week': ['2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42', '2022-42'],
                   'Case': [540, 540, 480, 480, 480, 465, 465, 310, 310],
                   'Team': ['Finance', 'IT', 'Sales', 'Finance', 'IT', 'IT', 'Sales', 'Legal', 'Marketing'],
                   'Case Info': ['OTHER', 'ACCEPTED', 'OTHER', 'CHECK CASE', 'OTHER', 'OTHER', 'OTHER', 'VALIDATED', 'OTHER']})

df['Case Info'] = df.groupby(['Case'], group_keys = False)['Case Info'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('OTHER',np.nan).bfill().ffill())

print(df)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  Year-Week  Case       Team   Case Info
0   2022-42   540    Finance    ACCEPTED
1   2022-42   540         IT    ACCEPTED
2   2022-42   480      Sales  CHECK CASE
3   2022-42   480    Finance  CHECK CASE
4   2022-42   480         IT  CHECK CASE
5   2022-42   465         IT         NaN
6   2022-42   465      Sales         NaN
7   2022-42   310      Legal   VALIDATED
8   2022-42   310  Marketing   VALIDATED
```

Ahora, en el `case` 465 todas las entradas dicen `OTHER` y por eso el código anterior devuelve `NaN` para esas filas, si quisieras que se conservara `OTHER` puedes agregar `fillna('OTHER')` al final de la línea donde se genera `Case Info`:

```
df['Case Info'] = df.groupby(['Case'], group_keys = False)['Case Info'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('OTHER',np.nan).bfill().ffill()).fillna('OTHER')
```

Esto devolvería el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  Year-Week  Case       Team   Case Info
0   2022-42   540    Finance    ACCEPTED
1   2022-42   540         IT    ACCEPTED
2   2022-42   480      Sales  CHECK CASE
3   2022-42   480    Finance  CHECK CASE
4   2022-42   480         IT  CHECK CASE
5   2022-42   465         IT       OTHER
6   2022-42   465      Sales       OTHER
7   2022-42   310      Legal   VALIDATED
8   2022-42   310  Marketing   VALIDATED
```